# Is there a way to define a hotkey via karabiner-elements for Emacs Anywhere instead of using the shortcut from Apple's System Preferences?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, emacs, karabiner

I really like a software program called [Emacs Anywhere](https://github.com/zachcurry/emacs-anywhere) and I’m looking to understand how it works as a service in the keyboard shortcuts preference pane on macOS Monterey.

Currently, I am following the instructions on the README file. Hence, I have defined a hotkey via macOS' GUI on `SystemPreferences/keyboard/shortcut/services/general`.

[image]

However, I am managing all my hotkeys with [Karabiner-elements](https://github.com/pdelfino/my-karabiner-elements-config). I like the text-driven approach via JSON file. This is [my config file](https://github.com/pdelfino/my-shortkeys-config). It is way more reproducible.

If I re-store this machine (or buy a new one) or share my config with a friend, it is just necessary to paste the text content.

Thus, I would like to ask, is it possible to configure this with a shell command?

For instance, this is how I can open the Brave browser:

```json
{
    "description": "left_command + b -> Brave",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "b",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_command"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "shell_command": "open '/Applications/Brave Browser.app'"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
}
```

What would be the terminal shell command to invoke Emacs-anywhere on macOS?